# when first creating table in doris, it occurs errCode = 2, detailMessage = Cluster default_cluster has no available capacity

Tags: olap

ddl sql

```
create table a (

`id` bigint not null ,
`update_time` datetime
)

DISTRIBUTED BY HASH(`id`) BUCKETS 1
PROPERTIES (
    "replication_allocation" = "tag.location.default: 1"
)
```

error msg
SQL 错误 [1105] [HY000]: errCode = 2, detailMessage = Cluster default_cluster has no available capacity

Answer (score 0):

Go to the be storage directory to see the storage space

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).